# Converting date to string for logfile, and then from string to DateTime for Database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, string-formatting, datetime-format

If I save the date and time in this format:

```
string sLogTime = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";
```

...what will I then have to do to convert that string into a recognizable value for a SQL Server DateTime column? Something like so:

```
   DateTime dtLogTime = Convert.ToDateTime(sLogTime);
   . . .
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@logDateTime", dtLogTime)); 
   . . .
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact`:

```
string pattern = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy";
DateTime parsedDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an exact parse:

```
DateTime dtLogTime = DateTime.ParseExact(sLogTime, "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Just make sure that you use a consistent culture info for both reading and writing. People often use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture for internal formats the user never sees which is English but not country-specific.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`, probably with the invariant culture. However, you should also be aware of what timezone the log is in. Use `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal` or `DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal` appropriately, or possibly neither. Fundamentally, `DateTime` is a bit tricksy about this, and you can easily end up doing the wrong thing. You should probably make sure that the `DateTime` you pass to your database is in UTC.

An alternative for the parsing part is to use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) which provides a bit more clarity (IMO) about how you're parsing etc. You can then convert to an appropriate `DateTime` to pass to your database.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt;
string Temp1 = "Your Date";
if (DateTime.TryParse(Temp1, out dt))
{
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@logDateTime", dt)); 
}
else
     cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@logDateTime", DateTime.Now));
```